How to Clone or Pull a Repository onto a Ubuntu Server via a .gitlab-ci.yml File
I have a repository hosted on GitLab.com and an EC2 instance running Ubuntu Server. I can SSH into the server and clone the repository and Apache2 serves it up just fine. But, how do I set up a .gitlab-ci.yml to automate that when I push changes.
I imagine the pipeline would use a key pair to login to the server via SSH and then run a few glab and git commands to pull down the changes
Is this possible?
So, far I've only been able to log into the server manually and run the glab and git commands. IE: glab auth login... and git clone...

I think the text of the question makes sense, but the title is misleading and doesn't really tell what you are asking. Make the title clearer.
